# Error message: Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : there are aliased coefficients in the model

Tags: r, error-handling, rank, anova

I'm trying to run an aligned rank transformation ANOVA on my non-normally distributed dataset.

The dataset has 2 predictors (categorical) and a continuous response variable

After running the following model I got this error message

*Error in Anova.III.lm(mod, error, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
there are aliased coefficients in the model*

`model <- art(response ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor1:predictor2, data = df)`

Just wondering if anyone knows why this may be and how I can fix this

Edit:

Package is ARTool

Reproducible example:

```
Length  Preditctor 1    Predictor 2
1   a   q
6   b   q
4   c   r
8   d   r
7   a   q
3   b   q
9   c   r
1   d   r
4   a   q
5   b   q
2   c   r
3   d   r
5   a   q
4   b   q
6   c   r
1   d   r
```

Comment: We need a **reproducible example**, please.  What package is `art()` from? It's conceivable that `X <- model.matrix(~predictor1*predictor, df); caret::findLinearCombos(X)` would help.

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but could you post the example data in a text format rather than as an image?

Comment: Just added it but not sure how to format it in stack overflow to get it to look more like a table sorry